# Enlarge image in XAML & keeping seperated pixels

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-store-apps

In a Windows Store App (C# / XAML) I'd like to show a 10x7 pixel grayscale image, but blown up so one can see the pixels. Unfortunately, by default XAML is blending neighbouring pixels like seen below, but I'd like to have sharp edges for each one so I can see where a pixel starts and where it ends. How can I achieve this?
[image]

Comment: Hve you tried embedding it in a `ViewBox` ?

Comment: just did, looks the same unfortunately.

Comment: By adjusting the size the of the viewbox, not the image?

Comment: sure, like this:
<Viewbox Height="483" Width="311">
<Image Height="10" Width="7"/>
</Viewbox>

Comment: Take the Height/Width off the image and try it.

Comment: nope, still the same :-/

Comment: Interesting, I'd have to think about it for a sec then. Glad I didn't try to post it as an answer

Comment: This is quite a bit late, but have you tried setting the `DecodeHeight` and `DecodeWidth` of the Image?